# escape character usage in bash, what do we actually escape?

Tags: bash

I am reading the bash manual, found the escape character [definition](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Escape-Character) pretty surprising, instead of **modifying** the meaning of every character follows it (as in Java / C):

> It **preserves** the literal value of the next character that follows

Does it mean in bash, we only use it to escape special meaning character like ', ", \, $

And other cases, like \t\e\s\t actually is exactly as test ? I verified that

`echo test`

`echo \t\e\s\t` 
outputs same result.

Comment: Echo does not emit data literally, and is unsuitable for this kind of testing

Comment: That is to say -- depending on both your shell release and on active runtime settings, `echo '\t'` may emit `t`, or it may emit a literal tab, or it may emit `\t`. The specification doesn't require any specific behavior when backslashes are present; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, especially the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Comment: In general, `[ test = \t\e\s\t ] && echo yes` is a more reliable test. You shouldn't see any difference in this specific case, but there are definitely places where visually comparing echo output misleads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean in bash, we only use it to escape special meaning character like ', ", \, $

Yes. Also, e.g. newline:

```
echo foo
bar
# foo
# -bash: bar: command not found

echo foo \
bar
# foo
# bar
```

> And other cases, like "\t\e\s\t" actually is exactly as "test"

If unquoted, yes. Quoted, the backslash is preserved. Some UNIX utilities do use backslash for "special meanings", but it is the utility, not `bash`, that gives those sequences meanings. Examples are `printf`, and GNU `echo` when given `-e` option:

```
/bin/echo \t\e\s\t
# test

/bin/echo "\t\e\s\t"
# \t\e\s\t

/bin/echo -e "\t\e\s\t"      # GNU version (will not do the same thing on Mac)
#         s       
# (tab)(escape)s(tab)

printf "\t\e\s\t"
#         s       
# (tab)(escape)s(tab)
```

As @rici reminds me, bash *can* interpret C-style escape sequences itself, if you use the special quotes of the form `$'...'`:

```
/bin/echo $'\t\e\s\t'
#         s
```

Here it really is `bash` that does it, not `echo`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, it helps clarify lot of myth seen previously.

Comment: It's not by any means guaranteed to be only when given `-e` that echo treats backslash-escape sequences as special. That'll happen in XSI-compatible POSIX sh implementations by default, and in bash as well when both posix and `xpg_echo` flags are active. (Moreover, the POSIX `echo` spec doesn't allow `echo -e` to do anything but print the string `-e` on output, so bash is simply out-of-compliance on that point).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: You're right, plain `echo` (as opposed to `/bin/echo`) is not the best example, as it's `bash` emulating GNU `/bin/echo` (so in a way, it _is_ bash interpreting the control characters, just not in the way that one might think).

Comment: Bash does interpret C-style escape sequences if you quote the string with `$'...'`. Alternatively, you can use `printf`, which may or may not be built-in but in both cases handles most C escape sequences. (Posix doesn't insist on `\x..` nor `\u....` but bash's builtin printf and the printf in gnu's coreutils both do.)